# Find random point on a circle with a radius of x and the players position as center (unity)

Tags: unity, sphere

First of all please note that the game is in 3d and **Not 2d**

The image below is seen from above. What I am trying to do is find a random point 2 - 3 meters around the player.

However I am not quite sure how to achieve it:

I have tried the following:

```
Vector3 randomPointOnCircle = Random.insideUnitSphere;
randomPointOnCircle.Normalize();
randomPointOnCircle *= radius;
return randomPointOnCircle;
```

However I am not sure how to set the player as the center?

[image]
*Star - Player*

*Square the general ground*

*Circle - A visual representation of where the points should be around the player*

Comment: Your current code selects a point on a sphere, not on a circle. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial application of the unit circle:

```
Vector3 RandomPointOnXZCircle(Vector3 center, float radius) {
    float angle = Random.Range(0, 2f * Mathf.PI);
    return center + new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, Mathf.Sin(angle)) * radius;
}
```